# How to create .anim file from .fbx file in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx

I am new in using Unity. In my game, models and animations are exported from 3DMAX as .fbx files, animations are clipped in Unity, but there's no .anim files generated, I need separated .anim files because the following code will not work even I have clipped animation "run":

```
var clip = animation["run"];
```

Can someone help me? thanks in advance.

[image: rig]
[image: model]
[image: animations]
[image: import settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the animations up in the importing. Select the *.fbx* model in Unity and go to **Animations** tab. There you have to define the clips. The *.anim* files will be generated under the model.

If you do not see the clips inside the animations tab, change the "Animation Type" under **Rig** to `Legacy`.

Comment: That helps, thanks Esa. I have followed your instructions and the code runs ok but still no .anim files are generated, can you explain the reason or show me some links?

Comment: @beyonddoor Could you add screenshots of your model import settings from Unity?

Comment: screenshots are attached.

Comment: @beyonddoor Looking at the screenshots everything looks OK. Even the run animation is listed in the animation component.

Answer (score 16):

I finally found the answer, pressing **CTRL+D** on animation clip in .fbx file will create a separate .anim file, what a strange operation!

Comment: Makes sense, ctrl D is duplicate. I guess it defaults to duplicating as a separate file.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a script to do this easily

[image]

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationExtractor: MonoBehaviour
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Extract Animation")]
    private static void ExtractAnimation()
    {
        foreach (var obj in Selection.objects)
        {
            var fbx = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(obj);
            var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fbx);
            CreateAnim(fbx, directory);     
        }
    }

    static void CreateAnim(string fbx, string target)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fbx);
        var filePath = $"{target}/{fileName}.anim";
        AnimationClip src = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<AnimationClip>(fbx);
        AnimationClip temp = new AnimationClip();
        EditorUtility.CopySerialized(src, temp);
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(temp, filePath);
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
    }
}
```